# Sublime not loading "Color scheme - default.sublime-package"

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, package, color-scheme

I opened the ~/Applications/Sublime Text.app/contents/MacOS/Packages/Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package with vim and changed some settings in the color theme that I was using. When I then saved the changes and restarted sublime text 3, the changed wasn't in effect (I tried multiple times and double checked everything).

1. Should you be able to just edit the package without extracting/unzipping anything? I read at different places that you should unzip and then edit, why is that?
2. Does ST3 read the color theme from somewhere else? Does this apply to all sublime-package files? A short explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be modifying anything in that folder. The changes you make there will get overwritten by whatever you have in your `Packages` folder anyways (not the Packages folder you went to). The correct `Packages` folder you want to go to can be found by doing *Preferences -> Browse Packages*.

---

The best way to make modifications to files in a package is to use a plugin called `PackageResourceViewer` which you can install with Package Control. Once you have it installed, just do the following:

1. Open up the command palette with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type in `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Use the arrow keys to find the package and file you want to make modifications to and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

If you'd like to see the entire contents of a package (all the folders and files inside it), just do the following and a folder with the package name will be created in your `Packages` folder

1. Open up the command palette with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type in `PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Use the arrow keys to find the package you want to extract and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Go to your `Packages` folder by doing *Preferences -> Browse Packages* and you will see the entire folder for your package.